# jQuery: Clear input field as soon as loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an input field I would like to clear it as soon as possible. If I put my script into  the DOM is not loaded. If I use document ready the input field was already visible for some time.

With .on() I can only react to events and `$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', func)` does not include inital DOM elements.

Also I can't place the JavaScript inline only as included javascript file.

Is there any way to get the input field fast?

Comment: Why is it not clear by default?

Comment: Would it be possible to put this data in a hidden field instead?

Comment: While you can't place JS inline, can you place a `<script src=` wherever you want?  Then you can get around "no inline js" requirement as it will be run where the `<script` tag is, but stored in a separate js file.

Comment: What *can* you do?  (as in, what are you allowed to do, not your ability to do so).  Can you change how the html is rendered? (there's no mention of server-side tech).  Can you set attributes on the html at design time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can apply the CSS:** display:none to the field.

After clear the field, remove the CSS: display:none

**Hope this helps"**

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants. I think he/she wants the field to be empty after the page has loaded, but before the field is visible.

Comment: Ummm, you can hide it with the css, then in ready method: clear it and show it again.

Comment: @Perplexor how can the field be not visible after the page has loaded? "after the page has loaded but before the field is visible" - doesn't make any sense - the field will be visible long before the page has loaded.  *unless* you apply this answer (set it when rendering the html)

Comment: I know. I think the question itself makes no sense, but maybe I've gotten something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you are talking about clearing a text field or something like that which the document will have at least 1 of that field and there is a/any event that will append similar text field to the document?

on load event and other similar event are not supported by event delegation

[source](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: btw i can see some people can make it work by declaring it in-line in the html element

Answer (score 0):

If `display: none;` is not a solution, try making text color similar to background-color of this input. And remove that rule when needed.